# OpenVPN not creating tun interface

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

For some reason OpenVPN is not creating the tun0 interface and I have no idea what to do anymore (kind of a noob).

This is my server.conf:

```
local 192.168.178.60
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# server and remote endpoints
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Server
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
# Add route to Client routing table for the OPenVPN Subnet
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
# your local subnet
push "route 192.168.178.60 255.255.255.0"
# Set your primary domain name server address to Google DNS 8.8.8.8
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 1
# This configuration file was originally written by Lauren Orsini at 
ReadWrite.
```

Anyone have an idea what to do?

Comment: Try using the `--mktun` option to make the `tun0` interface before OpenVPN starts.

Comment: This may be a noobish question, but where should I add that option?

Comment: Use `verb 4` to get some more logging. Also, you did start it as `root`, right?

Comment: Yes, I started the service as root.

Comment: I got an error:

Comment: Wed Jul 26 15:07:12 2017 us=620792 Options error: options --mktun or --rmtun should only be used together with --dev
Wed Jul 26 15:07:12 2017 us=621411 Exiting due to fatal error

Comment: Nevermind, I added the --mktun to the server.conf.

Comment: It shouldn’t be necessary. In fact, it’s a standalone command. Again, please raise the verbosity and look at the log file. Do not put `mktun` in your config file.